# Uri is accepting domain without root?

Tags: c#, uri

I trying to understand why Uri object is accepting this URL:

```
http://test/dir/page?id=1
```

I'm loading this URL with this code:

```
    string u = "http://test/dir/page?id=1";
    Uri url;
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(u, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
        throw new InvalidUrlException(u);
```

For me, this URL is seems missing.

What do you think?

Comment: FYI, it's not a C# URI. It's a .NET URI.

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid URL when your local server name is `test`.